# Cohomology of central extensions of groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let G be a central extension of a finite group H by $Z/2$. I need an explicit description of the differentials $d_2$ and $d_3$ in the Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence which converges to the cohomology of G with coefficients in either $Z/2$ or $U(1)$. It appears that $d_2$ is related to the cup product with the extension class, while $d_3$ is related to the Bockstein of the extension class, but I could not find it in any standard books on cohomology of groups.

Comment: The paper by Johannes Heubschmann mentioned in Andy Putman's answer to this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/590/differentials-in-the-lyndon-hochschild-spectral-sequence?rq=1 might have some useful information. You could also try using Kudo's Transgression theorem to make sense of your claim about $d_3$.

Comment: We've done lots of computations for $H=Z/2$, see pages 14-17 in http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0701071. There we used a so-called 7-term exact sequence in order to determine $d_2$. Maybe that can help, good luck!

Answer (score 7):

Ok, maybe not in a standard book, but a classic anyway: the description of the differentials $d_2$ and $d_3$ can be found in the paper

- J.-P. Serre. [Cohomologie modulo 2 des complexes d'Eilenberg–MacLane](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02564562). Comment. Math. Helv. 27 (1953), 192-232. ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=60234))

As expected in the question, $d_2$ is the cup product with the extension class and $d_3$ is related to the Bockstein of the extension class via the product structure on the $E_3$-page.
I actually found this in the introduction of the following paper

- I. Leary. [A differential in the Lyndon–Hochschild–Serre spectral sequence](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002240499390019P). JPAA 88 (1993), 155-168. ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1233320))

which gives some more discussion and identifies the $d_4$-differential.